# limit number of files to be uploaded in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

In my MVC application, i have information upload form. Here user can upload videos and images. To do this i have created to file controls, one for videos and one for images. Here user should be only able to upload at max 2 videos and at max 5 images for single form. Can any one suggest me how can i limit the user to upload number of files. i.e. if only 2 videos and 5 images also where should i implement this for best use? in `controller` or using `javascript`?

Comment: `Where?` - Both. Limit it in the browser (via javascript) for ease of use, limit in on the back end as well for server side validation. `How?` - too broad, do some research and write some code. If you get stuck ask a question on so but please read [ask] before posting and include an [mcve].

Comment: Generate unique id for that form and add combination of that unique id and userid in any storage medium to track activity like uploading activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using javascript

File upload control :

```
<input type="file" id="t" name="t" onchange="checkFilesCount(this)" multiple>
```

javascript code :

```
function checkFilesCount(id) {
    if(id.files.length > 5)
    {    
        alert('you cant upload files more than 5');
        document.getElementById("t").value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The MVC file upload approach:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

This passes a `HttpPostedFileBase` to the controller or if you have multiple `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`. You can then evaluate the number of files and file types and return any functionality/messages back to the user.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {...
```

Or

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="file" />
<input type="file" name="files" id="file" />

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {...
```

Comment: from controller it can be achieved, but using javascript if i want to do then how can i do so? like it should directly show the popup when user selects more than 5 files from upload window and clicks on `Ok` button. :(